# Does Consult The Prisoner move jump track again, after an auto-jump?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, exodus

Here's the scenario:

- The fleet is one away from
  auto-jumping, i.e. at the -1 location
  on the jump track
- Consult The Prisoner is drawn during
  the Crisis step
- Current Player chooses to attempt the
  skill check
- Humans pass the skill check
- The jump track is advanced to
  auto-jump (from passing the check)
- The jump is resolved

What happens next? Do we still resolve the Activate Cylon Ships (there are none) and Prepare For Jump steps? I see no reason not to, but it just seemed a little odd. So the fleet moves to the second spot on the jump track, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The situation is a little strange, but it's clear that the card is intended to increase the jump track twice on a passed check, and the rules for resolving cards are clear.